# How to permanently block a website in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, blocking

Is there a way to block websites in windows permanently? for example something similar to windows HOSTS file but once an ip is added to the file it can't be removed even by the the person who added it. Any ideas?

Comment: If a user has ability to add a hostnane to the hosts file... That user can also remove it.

Comment: yes, that's why i'm looking for an alternative, a different mechanism

Comment: If the main concern is only within your network, most modern routers support url blocking.  Another option is to have the router point to another DNS service (such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)) and block at that level.  However, there are **always** ways around these types of blocks.  At some point you either need to talk with the person you are trying to restrict (or find someone to hold you accountable, if it's you).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a router which only you have access to, you may be able to **blacklist** (AKA Parental Controls) the website from there. The downside is that most consumer routers block the site for the entire network, not sure if that would be a problem in your case.

Examples: [image] :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can add it, you can remove it. To sorta arrive at what you're wanting. Create standard user for your Windows 7 machine. Log in as admin and setup the HOSTS file as desired. Change the admin password to something you can never remember then log back out. Yes, I am laughing, but it gives you want you want.

Answer (score 0):

**[Cold Turkey](http://getcoldturkey.com/)** can do that. It is designed to not be easily stopped once you have started it.

Its relevant features (quoting its website):

> - Block Sites - Use the default list of popular sites to block, or add any number of your own to the list.
> - Computer Wide - Cold Turkey's blocking features are computer-wide, which will affect all users and browsers on the computer.
> - Schedule your Block - Cold Turkey can be scheduled to block you in intervals of a half an hour, up to a full week!
> - Unstoppable - Cold Turkey can't be stopped easily as it is not stoppable from the system tray or the task manager.

[image: Cold Turkey screenshot]

Comment: Just a warning, the Cold Turkey service CTService.exe had over 1GB of RAM allocated and periodically using high CPU and causing my laptop CPU fan to spin up, even when *inactive* (the blocker hasn't been enabled this week).  So uninstalled.